# JSON and Android. Can't Convert json string to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I am trying to convert following json string to `JSONObject` in android. But it throws `JSONException`. I have been digging up my mind for past few hours. Please help.

JSON String :

```
parseExchangeRate({"query":
             {"count":1,"created":"2012-09-07T18:49:32Z","lang":"en-US","results":
                       {"row":{"rate":"55.395","name":"USD to INR"}}}});
```

Exception:

```
Value <jsonobject>parseExchangeRate( of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Code :

```
String result = convertStreamToString(instream);
Log.d(TAG, result); //this outputs the above stated string
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result); // this line thows exception
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loose the 'parseExchangeRate()'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the JSON string? you state that it's,

```
parseExchangeRate({"query":
              {"count":1,"created":"2012-09-07T18:49:32Z","lang":"en-US","results":
                        {"row":{"rate":"55.395","name":"USD to INR"}}}});
```

but that looks like a line of javascript code. JSON != javascript. it looks like your web service is passing back a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) response. that's fine, but since you are not a javascript client, you need to parse out the actual JSON string from that response.

```
String result = convertStreamToString(instream);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*?\\((.*?)\\);$", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
if (m.matches()) {
  String json = m.group(1);
  JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json);
  ...
} else {
  // whoops
}
```